# Use an parameter value as array name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, parameters

I have a problem regarding following Codelines:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getJsonDataToSelect("ajax/json/assi.hotel.json", '#assi_hotel', 'hotelName');
});
function getJsonDataToSelect(url, id, key){
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: url,
                    success: function(hotels){
                        $.each(hotels, function(){
                        $(id).append('<option value="'+ this.key +'">'+ this.key +'</option>')
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

The json data looks like this:

```
[
    {"hotelName":"hotel1"}, 
    {"hotelName":"hotel2"}, 
    {"hotelName":"hotel3"}
]
```

I need to use "key" as the "hotelName" (arrayname). Just in advance, there is no possibility to name it in a different way.. it's appointed so. Obviously this won't work because, "key" is not defined as a arrayname in the Json-File.

My question is, is there any way, that JQuery uses the parametervalue and not the parametername itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change two times `this.key` ---> `this[key]`.

Comment: Is requirement to utilize `hotelName` as both `option` `value` _and_ `option` text - _not_ `hotel1` for `option` text ?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change two times this.key ---> this[key].

Thanks to Martin Ernst.

Answer (score 0):

There is no jQuery way but there sure is native javascript way. You can use `Object.keys` which returns the keys of objects passed in as the parameter.

```
hotels.forEach(function(obj){
   console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // array of keys of obj
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but that was not the answer i was looking for... But it helped me solving another problem :)